# Stuck in infinite loop in ocaml while calculating Pi approximation using Viete's formula

Tags: ocaml, pi, approximation

I have problem when calculating Pi approximation with given precision. I've concluded that the infinite loop problem is caused by my loop exit condition however I don't know what the exact problem is. In my opinion the exit condition should be something like

```
abs(current_aproximation - previous_approximation) < precision
```

Here is the code:

```
let pi(prec) = 
let rec loop(curr, prev) = 
    if(abs_float( (2. /. curr) -. (2. /. prev) ) < prec) then  // problematic line
        (2. /. curr)
    else
        loop(curr *. sqrt(2. +. curr) /. 2., curr)
    in loop(sqrt(0.5), 1.);;
```

Thanks for any tips on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing a different product: after one iteration, you should have calculated sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(2+sqrt(2))/2 but you calculate sqrt(2)/2 * sqrt(2+sqrt(2)/2)/2.

What about this algorithm?

```
let pi prec =
   let rec p2 xn root =
     let nroot = sqrt(2. +. root) in
     let xm = xn *. (nroot /. 2.) in
     if (abs_float (( 2. /. xm ) -. (2. /. xn))) < prec
     then xm
     else p2 xm nroot
   in 2. /. (p2 1.0 0.0)
```

it evaluates to:

```
# pi 0.1 ;;
- : float = 3.12144515225805197
# pi 0.01 ;;
- : float = 3.14033115695475251
# pi 0.001 ;;
- : float = 3.14127725093277288
# pi 0.0001 ;;
- : float = 3.14157294036709134
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I must have missed that part of calculation. I have a one more side question - does the performance of the code increases when fewer arguments are passed into recursive function or is it just personal preference?

Comment: Do you mean the difference between p2 as a closure binding prec versus adding prec as an additional argument to the inner function? I guess that depends on the compiler, but I can imagine that the closure is translated to the second version anyway. In this particular case, p2 is only created once anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your code to print out the value of `curr`, you'll notice  that you quickly reach a fixpoint:

```
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
9.88131291682e-324
(...)
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula) your initial value should be `(sqrt 2.) /. 2.` rather than `sqrt (0.5)`. But even with this modification, it's impossible to request a precision any smaller than `0.61` without hitting the fixpoint described earlier.

My guess is that `float`s are not precise enough to express this algorithm that way.

Comment: `sqrt(2)/2` and `sqrt(0.5)` are equal, and floating precision can't lead to such errors. The algorithm implementation is wrong.